# After loading my project from git on a different computer, com.unity.ugui scripts break

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\EventSystem\EventData\BaseEventData.cs(44,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'EventSystem' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\UI\Core\DefaultControls.cs(140,61): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Selectable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

```
Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ugui@1.0.0\Runtime\EventSystem\InputModules\PointerInputModule.cs(10,48): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BaseInputModule' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I got over 100 errors in Safe Mode similar to this. All the errors are saying that some namespace or element doesn't exist in the com.unity.ugui script. It all happened after I cloned my repo and opened it. There were no errors when I commited.

I tried something with the Input System packages but that did not do anything. I tried reinstalling but I'm not sure if it did because it's a dependency.

[Here is a screenshot of some errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZKEq.png)

Comment: What happens if you don't go into safe mode? What's the first error in your list of errors after you clear errors? Is the Unity version the same between computers? All the errors you posted appear to originate in the package cache - are you sure all your packages are the same version as the source computer? How is your gitignore setup on the source computer?

Comment: Same version. exiting safe mode is the same errors. Seems to be a git issue since first computer works totally fine

Comment: What about all the other questions I asked? When you clear the errors, only "real" errors remain. What's the first one in the list? How are your packages setup? How is your gitignore setup?

Comment: The errors are the exact same, I can go back tommorow and get you the first error since it  is only on the other computer. I don't understand fully what you mean by how your package are setup but they are in the Packages folder of my project. Packages: https://gyazo.com/ce5972db5af53165b46ef0bedcbef463. My gitignore is this: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Unity.gitignore. I placed it in the Unity project folder that holds the Assets, Packages, etc. folders.

Comment: Check the Unity UI package and see what its version is. Upgrade it if possible. Restart and see what happens.